# Cannot get to Age 2

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

While playing The Asian Dynasties expansion pack with Age of Empires III, it would not let me get to Age 2 for some reason with Beijing. I have enough food to upgrade to Age 2 but it will still won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Beijing, you must have a villager selected and then select "Upgrade to Age #".

Answer (score 1):

To age up with any Asian civilization, You need to build a building called a wonder. Your villagers can build them.